# No module named matplotlib when running from script

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on `windows 10 64bit` and for coding in python I use mainly winpython and spyder because in past I have had very big issues with installing `scipy` package.

Few days ago I finally have success with installing python (version 3.6.2) and I completed installing numpy,scipy and matplotlib with pip and wheel type of files.

When I try to open IDLE and try to plot something very easy, it works fine but when I try to run a script I wrote before with spyder it returns me error as you can see on my printscreen. Can anybody help me?

Printscreen:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a file called `matplotlib.py` which is shadowing the `matplotlib` package and is causing some problems. Try renaming your `matplotlib.py` script to something else.

Comment: This caused my problem, I overlooked that file. Thanks!